# Extracting Facebook Managed accounts (pages) in Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, social-media

I want to use Mathematica to explore various relationships on my Facebook pages. I've been able to successfully extract information on my personal Facebook page using the build in Social Media commands in MMA v9. My FB account also has me as Manager/Admin on a couple of accounts that my company maintains, i.e., pages without separate FB logins. I'm curious if it is possible to extract this data directly using MMA?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use "apps" from such managed accounts?

Comment: Without further details, I believe this is a duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11673/7167).